# What is the difference between int{10} and 10?

Tags: c++, c++11

As the title, I have two expressions:

```cpp
int&& a = const_cast<int&&>(int{10});
int&& a = const_cast<int&&>(10);
```

The first compiling passed, but second not. Why is this happening?

In my view, it's because 10 is a literal and int{10} is a unamed variable. Is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reason why your first conversion passed is a bug in g++. Neither code is legal, and both clang and icc reject it.

They even give a good message:

> error: the operand of a const_cast to an rvalue reference type cannot
> be a non-class prvalue

This does make sense, since both `10` and `int{10}` are [prvalues](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), and you can not bind a reference directly to prvalue. Instead, when references are initialized, compiler [materializes the temporary variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization) and binds a reference to it. However, there are no rules for materializing temporary variables for `const_cast` - so there is nothing to bind the reference to.